# Integration of the following

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the definite integral of 
$$
\int_0^1 \left(\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\right)'\cdot\frac{1}{g(x)}\,dx,
$$
where the conditions are as follows:

$f(0) = 2 $

$f(1) = 3 $

$f'(x) $ is continuous

For all $x$ in the range $\{0,1\}, f(x)^2-g(x)^2=1$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just be to sure, you want the definite integral from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$, right?

Comment: Yes sorry I missed that out, I'll edit it now

Comment: $\displaystyle\;\int_0^1 \frac{1}{g} d\left(\frac{g}{f}\right)
= \left[\frac{1}{f}\right]_0^1 + \int_0^1 \frac{g}{f} \frac{dg}{g^2}\;$
and $gdg = fdf$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By integration by parts,

\begin{align}\int_0^1 \left(\frac{g}{f}\right)' \frac{1}{g}\, dx &= \frac{g}{f}\cdot \frac{1}{g}\bigg|_{t = 0}^{t = 1} - \int_0^1 \frac{g}{f}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{g}\right)\, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{f(1)} - \frac{1}{f(0)} + \int_0^1 \frac{g'}{fg}\, dx\\
&= -\frac{1}{6} + \int_0^1 \frac{g'}{fg}\, dx.
\end{align}

Differentiating both sides of the equation $f^2 - g^2 = 1$, we get $2ff' - 2gg' = 0$, or $ff' = gg'$. So $g'/f = f'/g$, in which case $$\int_0^1 \frac{g'}{fg}\, dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{f'}{g^2}\, dx = \int_0^1 \frac{f'}{f^2 - 1}\, dx = \int_{2}^{3} \frac{du}{u^2 - 1} = \frac{1}{2}\log\left|\frac{u - 1}{u + 1}\right|\bigg|_{u = 2}^{u = 3} = \frac{1}{2}\log\frac{3}{2}.$$

Hence $$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{g}{f}\right)'\frac{1}{g}\, dx = -\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{2}\log\frac{3}{2}.$$

Comment: Wow thank you so much! One question, at the start for integration by parts, you took $u = 1/g$ and $dv = (g/f)'$ correct?

Comment: @Eric correct! :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I have one additional question about this part: $\frac{1}{2}\log\left|\frac{u - 1}{u + 1}\right|\bigg|_{u = 2}^{u = 3} = \frac{1}{2}\log\frac{3}{2}.$ when u = 3 and u = 2, if we've taken u to be the function f then u = 3 and u = 2 respectively means f (1) and f(0)? I'm wondering how we end up with log (3/2)? Thank you!

Comment: @Eric yes that's right. The substitution was $u = f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating by parts we get $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{g}d(\frac{g}{f})=\frac{1}{f(1)}-\frac{1}{f(0)}+\int_0^1\frac{gdg}{fg^2}$$
Differentiating $f^2-g^2=1$ and replacing in the integral in the RHS of the above $gdg$ par $fdf$ et $g^2$ par $f^2-1$ we get $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{g}d(\frac{g}{f})=-\frac{1}{6}+\int_0^1\frac{fdf}{f^2-1}$$

Comment: You're welcome Eric